# How can I make grouping optimize?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, preforking

Here is my query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT Count(1), 
       user_id, 
       type 
FROM   (SELECT e.user_id, 
               e.type, 
               Max(r.date_time) last_seen, 
               e.date_time      event_time 
        FROM   events e 
               JOIN requests r 
                 ON e.user_id = r.user_id 
                    AND e.type IN( 3, 5, 6 ) 
        GROUP  BY e.user_id, 
                  e.date_time, 
                  e.type 
        HAVING last_seen < event_time) x 
GROUP  BY user_id, 
          type
```

Also here is the result of `EXPLAIN` :

[image]

Also here is the result of that subquery (`x`) `EXPLAIN`:

[image]

See? Much optimal. So the issue is grouping here. Any idea how can I make that query better?

---

**EDIT:** We need two tables:

1. `requests` table -- A new row will inserted inside it for each users request. So, the last (biggest) determines user's last time been online in our website somewhat.
2. `events` table -- A new row will be inserted inside it for each answer, comment.

We're talking about a Q/A website. All we're trying to do is "sending an email to the users who got a new comment/answer after their last time being online in our website".

Comment: Post your tables schema and explain as plain text not images please

Comment: i advice your this read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide table structures `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` (for every table involved in the question) also provide example data and expected result.. there might be better methods to get the same results faster or more optimized.. Also give your MySQL version you can get it with `SELECT VERSION();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite the query like this:

```
select user_id, type, count(*)
from (select e.user_id, e.type, e.date_time, 
             (select max(r.date_time)
              from requests r
              where r.user_id = e.user_id
              ) as last_seen 
       from events e 
       where e.type  in ( 3, 5, 6 ) 
      ) er
where last_seen < date_time
group by user_id, type;
```

Then, I want to be sure that there are indexes on `requests(user_id, date_time)` and `events(type, user_id, date_time)`.

Comment: Hence my alternate option by adding a lastRequest field per user.  Then you don't have to keep requerying the consistently growing Requests table.  Just get all events per user with the known last request date and the event date is AFTER the person was last contacted based on the qualified event type.

Comment: @DRapp . . . I would try this with the appropriate indexes first.  Maintaining such a field is a lot of work for the database, and requiring maintaining a bunch of triggers as well as other code.

Comment: Really? a single trigger to Update UserTable set lastRequest = date where userid = userId doing the insert?  I don't see difficulty or complex

Comment: @DRapp Probably adding a new filed named last_seen would make my current target much more easy to achieve. But you know, I'm a php developer at work. I don't access to databases and been reminded to stop touching database structure. Anyway, as I've commented under your post, [this](https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/521340fefb2f87cc37acd2a051ad7c01) 
 *(and also Gordon solution)* takes `0.1` sec to be executed (on a large dataset). I guess that would be known as a normal performance.

Comment: @MartinAJ, understood, and not knowing people's extent of access, can offer suggestions, but do understand when you are restricted.

Answer (score 2):

you need proper index on your table to match both the WHERE clause and Order by to help optimize.

```
table      index on...
events     ( type, user_id, date_time )
requests   ( user_id, date_time )
```

I might even suggest slight adjust of query.
Change your

```
AND e.type IN( 3, 5, 6 )
```

to

```
WHERE e.type IN( 3, 5, 6 )
```

Because the "e.Type" is based on your primary table of the query and has nothing to do with the actual JOIN to the requests table.  The join should represent actual columns to qualify between tables.

SUGGESTION post edit to question.  I might offer an alternate option.  Add a column to your user table for "lastRequest" date/time field.  Then, whenever a request is entered for that user, update the field in the user table.  You don't need to keep subquery max() to find out when.  This might simplify your query to something like...  As your request table gets larger, so too will your query time.  By looking directly at the user table ONCE for the already known latest request, you have your answer.   Query 10k users, or 2mil requests... your choice to plow through :)

```
select 
      u.user_id,
      e.type,
      count(*) CountPerType,
      min( e.date_time ) firstEventDateAfterUsersLastRequest
   from
      user u
         join events e 
            on u.user_id = e.user_id
           AND e.type in ( 3, 5, 6 )
           AND e.date_time > u.lastRequest
   group by
      u.user_id,
      e.type
```

So your join already has an underlying date/time per user and you can just look for those records coming in AFTER the person last requested something (hence follow-up).

Then, to prepare the new column in your user table you could just update with the max( request.date_time ) per user.

If a person is active as of ex: Nov 27th, and there are 5 responses to 3 different event types AFTER that, you still get that person per their Nov 27th date, yet other people could have newer or older "latestRequest" dates.

Just an optional thought..

Comment: [Better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqNzI.png), upvote. But sadly still it takes 5 sec to be executed on the real dataset.

Comment: In comparison to what previously... Also, what is purpose of the HAVING the last time seen before the event.  Why would someone request about an event AFTER the event happened?  You might want to edit and clarify in your original post.

Comment: @MartinAJ, for the index, it should be a SINGLE INDEX for all THREE fields, not individual indexes one per column... that is a BIG difference.  Also the REQUEST table should have a SINGLE index on BOTH fields, not one per each column.

Comment: Oh you mean the first index in your answer is composite *(which currently is)* and the second one is two separated indexes?

Comment: @MartinAJ, no.. both are 1 index each table... both are composite indexes.  If you don't need the other indexes on the table that are individual fields, I might consider removing, provided the first ordinal column in the index is the same, but I would ensure the events table has the type in the first position of the index.

Comment: I see .. also I've edited my question and explained what I'm trying to do .. please take a look at it.

Comment: Most likely the MySQL optimizer would rewrite the SQL `ON e.user_id = r.user_id 
                    AND e.type IN( 3, 5, 6 )` already to `ON e.user_id = r.user_id 
                    WHERE e.type IN( 3, 5, 6 )` under the hood already.. So i doubt your rewrite suggestion will help.. the indexes indeed will help.

Comment: @MartinAJ, see revised per your comment per another option to prevent subquery every time.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not able to add a new column to the user's table. But I wrote the query [this way](https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/7a1997112f81aa2e020a1d25a318d956) which has a better performance (about 1.5 sec). Any idea?

Comment: oh wow .. the execution time of [this](https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/521340fefb2f87cc37acd2a051ad7c01) is `0.1`. yay for me.

Comment: @DRapp . . . This does not implement the same logic.  This query is filtering the dates to only consider requests *before* the event date.  The OP's query is filtering out events where the most recent request is *after* the event date.

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c73878/1

```
ALTER TABLE `events` ADD INDEX e_type (type);
ALTER TABLE `events` ADD INDEX user_time (user_id, date_time);
ALTER TABLE requests ADD INDEX user_time (user_id, date_time);

SELECT  COUNT(*),
        e.user_id, 
        e.type
FROM `events` e 
JOIN  (
  SELECT user_id, Max(r.date_time) last_seen
  FROM requests r 
  GROUP BY user_id
) r
ON e.user_id = r.user_id 
   AND e.date_time > r.last_seen
WHERE e.type IN( 3, 5, 6 ) 
GROUP  BY e.user_id,  
       e.type
```

Comment: Your query will work, but they are looking for performance improvements and your simulated data is minimal per the mass they have in production.  Also, my suggestion to add a "lastReviewed" column to the user's table would prevent having to regroup every user through every request every time.  The larger the table, the constantly increasing subquery time.

Comment: Thank you .. upvote .. but as @DRapp mentioned, the issue is about the performance.

Comment: @MartinAJ just provide some data sample please and what is your current speed?

Answer (score 0):

See if this gets the 'right' answers:

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT(e.date_time),
        e.user_id, e.type
    FROM  events e
    JOIN  requests r  ON  e.user_id = r.user_id
                     AND  e.type IN( 3, 5, 6 )
    GROUP BY  e.user_id, e.type
    HAVING  MAX(r.date_time) < e.event_time
```

Indexes:

```
e:  INDEX(type)   -- may be useful (depends on cardinality)
r:  INDEX(user_id, date_time)  -- in this order
```